# Lychrel Numbers Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck on this question:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NNgUZtB5wy89DaROVNMy22Hfjt3gbwlq9qkMszU8Bu8/edit?usp=sharing
^the link

If you don't trust the link, here is the question:

> Loops: Lychrel Numbers
>
> Large Program Practice
>
> If we take 47, reverse the digits and add, we get 47+74 = 121, which is a palindromic number.  this means the number remains the same when its digits are reversed.  Not all numbers produce palindromes so quickly.  For example:
> 349+943 = 1292
> 1292+2921 = 4213
> 4213 + 3124 = 7337
> So, for the number 349, it took three iterations to arrive at a palindrome.
>
> Although no one has proved it yet, it is thought that some numbers, like 196 never produce a palindrome no matter how many iterations are carried out.  Such a number is called a Lychrel Number.  Surprisingly, there are palindromic numbers that are themselves Lychrel numbers; the first example is 4994.
>
> Write a program that reads one integer number and outputs YES if the input is a Lychrel number and NO otherwise.  In addition, if an input number is NOT a Lychrel number, your program must output the number of iterations it took to arrive at a palindrome and the final palindromic number.  By forcing the user input to be below 10000, you may assume that the number either becomes a palindrome in under 50 iterations or is a Lychrel number.
>
> Sample Program Execution:
>
> Input:        349
>
> Output:   NO  3   7337
>
> Input:        196
>
> Output:   YES
>
> Input:        89
>
> Output:   NO  24  8813200023188
>
> Input:        592
>
> Output        YES

This is what I have so far. I don't understand what I need to do to make it work. I am new to Stack Overflow so if I did anything wrong please let me know. Thanks!

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            Number: <input type='text' id='number' name='number' placeholder='1234'/> </br>
            Re-enter the same number: <input type='text' id='number2' name='number2' placeholder='1234'/>
            <button onclick='convert()'>Convert</button></br>
            <div id='result'></div>
            <script>
                function convert(){
                    var originalNum=parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
                    
                    var newNum=parseInt(document.getElementById('number2').value);
                    var x;
                    var total=originalNum;
                    var palindrome=false;
                    
                    for (x=0; x<50; x++) {
                        newNum==newNum.split("").reverse().join();
                        total+=newNum;
                            if (total==total.split().reverse().join()){
                                palindrome=true;
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                    if (palindrome)
                        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=("NO");
                    else
                        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=("YES");
                    
                    
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Linking to off site resources is not a good idea since they may disappear.  Rather you should copy the text of the document into the question.

Comment: What do you mean they disappear?

Comment: Tibrogargan- could u possibly answer my question?

Comment: The document you linked to could be deleted, or google could decide to move it so the link becomes invalid.  Happens all the time

Comment: Ohh okay. Got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there's better ways to do it, but this works.

The main issue you were running into was that JavaScript does different things with the `+` operator depending on the type of a variable.  For strings, it concatenates them but for numbers it adds them.  This can be especially confusing since the behavior for different operators is inconsistent.  i.e. it will evaluate `"5" == 5` as true (i.e.  It converts strings to numbers for `==`, but not for `+`)

Similarly for split and join.  They have different behaviors when used with no arguments, although they may seem like they are the inverse of each other.

```js
function lychrelTest() {
    var originalNum=document.getElementById('number').value;
    if (isNaN(parseInt(originalNum))) {
        alert('"'+originalNum+'" is not a number');
        return;
    }

    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    result.innerHTML = "";

    var current=originalNum;
    var palindrome=false;
    var x;
    for (x=0; x<50; x++) {
        var rev = current.split("").reverse().join("");
        var attempt = current + "+" + rev;
        current = (parseInt(current) + parseInt(rev)).toString();
        result.innerHTML += attempt + "="+ current + "<br />";
        if (current == current.split("").reverse().join("")) {
            palindrome=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    result.innerHTML+=(palindrome?("NO: "+current+" after "+(x+1)+" iterations"):"YES");
}
```

```html
<body>
 Number: <input type='text' id='number' name='number' placeholder='1234'/>
 <button onclick='lychrelTest()'>Test</button></br>
 <div id='result'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I love you, Tibrogargan, with all my life you are simply an amazing human being. Have a wonderful life, you saved me 9 hours of torture. Thank you so so so so so so so much. -Love, Namita

Comment: Tibrogargan -- it's a good idea where possible to lead the OP towards the answer without actually doing their work/homework for them, lest they actually learn nothing.

Comment: @EngineerDollery perhaps you should add "At the risk of sounding condescending" to the start of that